# What is less bad for SEO: to have a <section> with no heading, or to hide the heading with CSS?

Tags: seo, html, heading, semantic-web, section

I have my document outlined in several `<section>`s, but according to the spec

> The theme of each section should be identified, typically by including a heading (h1–h6 element) as a child of the section element.

What if I don't need a heading in a specific section?
What would be a good advice, not to have a heading at all or to hide it with CSS?

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller i don't think there is any duplication here. The issue i have is that my markup consists of several <section>s  and i want i.e. in the 3rd section not to have a heading title at all. However, 'typically' a section tag should have a heading child. So, the question is what is less harmfull: to have a section with no title at all or to keep the title but hide it somehow?

Comment: The other question asks specifically about hiding heading using CSS.  The answer says not to do that.   It also addresses the question of whether or not the headers are needed (they are not).

Comment: i am aware of the fact that hiding a heading is bad technique. The other question is talking about headings in general and from an importance point of view. It has nothing to do with the spec's description about the <section> tag, which is what i am asking. Spec sais:
 Each <section> should be identified, typically by including a heading (<h1>-<h6> element) as a child of the <section> element. What i am simply asking is that in front of the dilemma: section tag with no heading child and css-hidden heading which would be less seo harmful? Anyway thanks for the point out though

Comment: The W3C guide is not for SEO.

Comment: The W3C guide is a guide for you to write valid html. Valid Html has impact on how your website will be crawled and indexed. So Stephen, W3C guide is not for SEO but it is directly related to it. Finally, i hope you comprehend how my question is completely different to the one you pointed me to, thus should not have been marked as duplicate. Cheers

Comment: Google has long said they don't care about valid HTML.   They index the web as they find it, not as it is supposed to be according to the spec.  They don't give any bonuses for validating.

Answer (score 1):

Hiding content is quite dodgy. I would avoid this where possible. Save the hiding and showing for interactive elements.

I would title the page appropriately with a H1, then each section I would assign a H2.

If you're exceeding ten sections you will still experience a slight hit on your SEO as I believe the limit is ten H2's before it is considered a downfall. But the limit is one H1 per page.

**Image has been added**

[image: H1 Proof]

As for having too many H2's - I am not going to break my site to proove my point. The knowledge is there - take it or leave it!

Comment: I agree about not hiding content, but I've never heard of limits on H1 and H2 tags for SEO.  Do you have a reference to back those statements up?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - I can only show the proof for the H1 tag. As for H2's I have fixed my sites to be free from these 'issues' and I am not willing to break my sites to replicate an issue.